# Python : Publish post on a facebook page targeting a specific locale using Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post on a FB page a post with a specific language with Python and the Graph API, but it doesn't seem to work :

```
graph.put_object(parent_object=page_id, connection_name="feed", message="post in english", targeting={'locales': [1004,]})
```

The post is published, but the targeting doesn't seem to work...

I tried other solutions (targeting={'locales': 1004} etc. but nothing change

I can't find any explanation on the documentation, could someone help me :) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found an answer, I tried to pass a dictionary to the targeting parameter, but I have to pass a string so, it's not :

```
targeting={'locales' : [1004]}
```

but

```
targeting="{\"locales\": \"[1004]\"}"
```

a little bit confusing, at least for me, but that's it, it works :)